# Is it OK to block a thread on application startup?

Tags: scala, playframework

In my Play app, I do this in `Module.configure()`:

```
   bind(classOf[GadgetsReader]).toInstance(GadgetsCsvReader)
   bind(classOf[Gadgets]).asEagerSingleton()
```

Then, I do this:

```
@Singleton
class Gadgets @Inject()(reader: GadgetsReader)  {
  val all:Seq[Gadget] = reader.readGadgets() 
}
```

That synchronously loads a large collection of gadgets from a CSVfile into memory on startup, in a Play's rendering thread.

I did not see a similar scenario implemented anywhere in Play examples. I would like to know whether what I am doing is idiomatic Scala & Play.

Is it OK to load a very large file synchronously like this, given that I don't want any requests served until the data is fully loaded?

Is it a good thing that I created a`Gadgets` class and then injected it, as opposed to a static/object method `Gadget.all`?

Should `Gadget` and `Gadgets` classes live under `model`?

Any other comments would be appreciated, too.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it depends how large, how fast you want your startup to be, etc. In general, I'd say yes, even Akka's cluster sharding has (or at least, last I read, had) a blocking call that waits for initialisation to complete before returning. In your case it's probably fine, but one gotcha with blocking calls like this is blocking generally means doing IO, and IO can fail (eg, what if you're reading from a network filesystem, and the network fails when you're starting up?). So sometimes, it's better to design your app so that it's capable of responding (perhaps with a not available status) without the operation having being done yet, and do that operation asynchronously, with retries etc in case it fails. But perhaps this is overkill in your case.

To answer your other questions - yes, it is definitely better to dependency inject `Gadgets` than use a static singleton, this means you can control how `Gadgets` is created (perhaps you might want to initialise it differently in tests).

It's probably fine to be in the `model` package, but this is greatly dependent on your domain and what it looks like.

Comment: I am already injecting GadgetReader; is there a need to inject both Gadgets and GadgetReader?